# Propane vs. Natural Gas - Indoor Air Quality?

Tags: natural-gas, stove, propane, air-quality

I've seen plenty of articles about gas stoves and the impact on indoor air quality. Specifically, there are reports of much higher CO2, NOx, PM 2.5 particulates, and formaldehyde, relative to electric stoves. However, I can't find any reference specifically to natural gas vs. propane.

How do natural gas and propane stoves compare in terms of indoor air quality.

Comment: For most people that is not a choice. Generally they get to choose between electrical and gas. Gas is dependent if natural gas is available or if they have to purchase propane. When doing the comparison also include the effects of generation, waste disposal, transmission losses, energy to maintain the lines, fuel lost with idle generators, etc.

Comment: The question is academic. I don't currently have a choice. I have propane, but most in my town have natural gas.

Comment: Electric stoves do not have any of those emissions at all, at least, not indoors.  Does the stove have exhaust ventilation?

Comment: This just doesn't feel like it's on topic here. Maybe [biology.se]? (maybe not) Since your research has led you to this information, I'd suggest further research on each type of gas to see what the output levels are, then make your own comparison. As noted, most people don't have the choice of gas type, is "gas or electric", so there probably aren't too many industry comparisons available. Also, unless there's a malfunction, the levels are low enough that they're not going to cause any harm unless you have a _very_ well sealed house and _zero_ air exchange.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Electric stoves actually do produce some of these things, because heating food causes them to be released. Gas stoves produce many times more than that due to the actual combustion, however, and in most homes hood vents are either not good enough or not used.

Comment: @FreeMan Here are some links to articles about how gas stoves are causing harm. Yes, proper adjustment helps, but also many (most?) people have insufficient ventilation. I also did some looking on Google Scholar for some actual research, but found nothing to help with my question.

https://www.vox.com/energy-and-environment/2020/5/7/21247602/gas-stove-cooking-indoor-air-pollution-health-risks

https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2020/10/gas-stoves-are-bad-you-and-environment/616700/

Comment: I stand by my statement that you're probably the first looking for a comparison. I'd suggest that you'll probably have to take whatever research you can find on emissions from NG stoves and from propane stoves and build your own comparison. I'm going to guess that such a comparison doesn't already exist or you'd have found it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement. Check out sustainable living SE.

Comment: @EdBeal It is related to my current home improvement project. I am considering getting my vintage propane stove restored as part of my kitchen remodel, and first want to get an idea if the air quality situation is going to be just as bad as what is being reported with natural gas, or better/worse. I could of course pay thousands to have the stove restored and then test it with various meters, but then I will have spent thousands already.

But yeah, I'm open to putting it elsewhere, just didn't know where when I posted.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a direct comparison, but you might just find something with hard numbers for propane stoves as they're an improvement on the alternatives (e.g. wood, charcoal) in some places

Comment: @ChrisH And that I'll definitely agree with - propane is going to be a *lot* safer, in many ways, than wood or charcoal.

Comment: @EdBeal I agree, so I flagged it for moderator intervention for a move. (didn't close vote, don't want it to arrive closed! LOL!)  Topically it's a *much* better fit for sustainable living SE, the people who care about this topic will be there not here, and honestly it would benefit from the question far more than here.

Comment: However, releases *from food* are moot to the question, since they will happen in all cases. And also could be mitigated by different cooking techniques.

Comment: I made a post myself over there on Sustainable Living SE. I guess I didn't realize it could be moved.

Answer (score 1):

### There is basically no significant difference, and if you want a new range and care about IAQ, just go induction anyway

The difference in emissions between a propane burner and a natural gas burner is quite small; this is to be expected, because they're really almost the same (many modern NG appliances can be converted to propane service by exchanging a few parts in the gas train).  However, a *newer* range is likely to perform somewhat better than a vintage appliance, mostly due to not running a pilot (or three) 24/7/365.  (It will emit about the same when you're cooking, but it's not starting off behind the 8-ball from what it's already put into the air.)

As a result, the real choice with ranges is "do you want combustion or not?"  It used to be the answer was "yes" if you had the choice to make, because electric resistance elements have inherent thermal inertia compared to a live flame, thus making them harder to handle for "dynamic" cooking operations like quick-frying.  This isn't an issue any longer, though, as *induction* technology has come of age, giving us responsive, combustion-free cooking that has other advantages as well, such as easy cleanup and superior precision (especially at low power settings).  Even though it's not without its downsides (induction cooking works with many clad pans and just about all cast iron ones, but not with copper cookware or the aluminum commonly used for nonstick-coated pans, and it requires the same wiring as an electric stove which can be a problem for some older houses that are gas-range-only), these options can be worked around by many, and induction also has a further benefit in this day and age in that you aren't contributing to demand for leaky gas infrastructure and its associated climate-change issues.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, the only significant outputs are:

- CO2 = Carbon Dioxide. This is a guaranteed result of burning any fossil fuel. CO2 is [dangerous in high concentrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13). But it is always present in the air at low concentrations (we produce it when we breathe) and with sufficient makeup air you should not have a problem.
- CO = Carbon Monoxide. This is an extremely dangerous gas that results from incomplete combustion. You can't smell it, so a carbon monoxide detector is a very good idea. But if your appliances are in good shape this should not normally be a problem.

If everything is working properly, you will get lots of CO2 and no CO. If things are not working properly, you will get some CO - and you definitely don't want that.

If you "smell gas", that is *not* from combustion, it is from the gas leaking instead of burning. That is dangerous if it builds up to explosive levels. The smell is actually added - natural gas doesn't have much of a natural smell. Mercaptan is commonly added to both natural gas and propane in order to provide the distinctive smell for safety purposes.

Comment: All of the things I listed in my original post are things that studies have shown exist in high levels in homes with gas stoves. I just want to understand the difference between propane and natural gas, in terms of those things.

Comment: For a person there is probably little difference between the two.  Main difference is the heat amount each puts outs, this is usually shown as BTUs per volume and cost per volume.   Most other differences you would need testing equipment to tell the difference.

Comment: @crip659 Propane produces a little more than twice as much energy for the fuel volume. This leads me to believe that it might be a bit more efficient (with fewer wasted byproducts) than natural gas. That's the reason I became curious and posed this question.

Comment: Most of the efficiently of burning will come from the appliance itself, than from the fuel.   A 90% propane and a 90% NG appliance should have almost the same byproducts/volume.

Comment: Natural Gas (methane) and propane are both simple Hydrocarbons - methane = CH4  combusts to become 1 CO2 + 2 H2O; propane = C3H8 combusts to become 3 CO2 + 4 H2O. Anything else is either from incomplete combustion (CO) or from impurities. Yes, the greenhouse gases (leaked gas itself, CO2 produced) are issues but as far as efficiency - both are very efficient/clean burning, unlike gasoline (lots of additives) and coal (usually far from pure C).

Comment: The OP has specifically stated they're worried about NOx; that concern is based on decent science. These oxides of nitrogen are produced when the flame heats the air enough for nitrogen and oxygen to combine ([Wikpiedia on N2O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide#Preparation_and_reactions)).  So you're wrong about significant outputs; more NOx would be expected than CO. H2O is also plentiful in the output, though not a hazard.  There's no need for impurities when we can react N2 from, and there's partial combustion.  Some good bits but doesn't really address the concerns.

Comment: @ChrisH "more NOx would be expected than CO" doesn't say much when expected CO should be nearly **0**. Feel free to write up a better answer. I stick by my original statements.

Comment: I might, if I could find sources and time - it's not as easy as you make out.  "CO should be 0" (on a non-faulty stove with plenty of air, which we may assume from the Q) is one of your valid points.  NOx is never going to be 0, and is reported to be enough to be a concern.   An answer that claims that a non-issue is more significant than something known to be a problem deserves my downvote

Comment: To me, NOx is a real but usually minor issue. CO is a rare but extremely *dangerous* issue - it could happen at any time due to unexpected problems (i.e., a stove that works fine one day and due to clogged burners, etc. all of a sudden has a problem) that could turn deadly very quickly. And it has readily available mitigation - CO detectors are inexpensive and very effective.